# Gradle build doesn't add version to package

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradlew

I'm creating a REST microservice using `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7` with `Gradle 4.2`.
When I build from Eclipse or run from console `./gradlew build`, the produced package in `build/libs` is named `$app.jar` instead of `$app-$version.jar`.

What am I missing? my build.gradle is the same as the `Spring Boot Docker GS` guide, and this problem prevent docker image to be built because the jar can't be found.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M7'
        springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.M5'
        gradleDockerVersion = '0.13.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker:${gradleDockerVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'networks'
    version = '0.9'
}

group = 'test'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone' }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'

    runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'junit:junit'
}

docker {
    name "${project.group}/${jar.baseName}"
    files jar.archivePath
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${jar.archiveName}"])
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because `build.gradle` is not provided.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question adding the `build.gradle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version should be specified outside `jar`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = "0.9"

jar {
    baseName = 'networks'
}
```

Comment: Moving it outside jar scope, works. I wonder how could work inside as stated in the official guide.. https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: Perhaps it is outdated syntax. The [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:version) states `version` should be specified in the most outer scope.